# How can I pass credentials while using NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I am trying to login to my own computer using the utorrent webui.

Currently I am using the following code:

```
- (void)login
{
NSURL *feedsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:12345/"];

NSString *user = @"username";
NSString *password = @"password";
NSURLCredential *defaultCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:user password:password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent];

NSString *host = [feedsURL host];
NSInteger port = [[feedsURL port] integerValue];
NSString *protocol = [feedsURL scheme];
NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc] initWithHost:host port:port protocol:protocol realm:nil authenticationMethod:NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic];

NSURLCredentialStorage *credentials = [NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage];
[credentials setDefaultCredential:defaultCredential forProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
[config setURLCredentialStorage:credentials];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:feedsURL completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
        if (httpResp.statusCode == 200) {
            NSLog(@"Woo! everything is working");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Hrmmm... error %@ occured", error);
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Hrmmm... error %@ occured", error);
    }

}] resume];
```

I can see the page just fine while using a desktop web browser, however, on my app it always returns a 401 error (not Authorised).

I guess this is because the credentials are not being used? If so, what is the correct way to use it? Also the NSURLSessionDelegate methods aren't being called. Is there something else that I have to do?

Comment: Did you check your port #?  I tried out your code and was getting 401's until if forced port 80 for the protectionSpace.  The port number retrieved from the URL is 0 in your example.  With port 80 I get the data from the URL!

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Basic will generally need a realm on the protection space; this is probably where it's failing. Check the authentication challenge headers being returned from the server using `curl -v` to find out what it is.

Other than that, the code you have listed should be working - I've just implemented something very similar and the credentials are being passed correctly. I've also experienced issues with the delegate authentication challenge method not being called.

Answer (score 0):

try and replace localhost with the computer IP address with the port