# NSURLSession, HTTP Basic Authentication and Self-Signed Certificate

Tags: basic-authentication, nsurlsession

I call a web service with the HTTPS scheme. To access to web service I need a username and password. I implemented the http basic authentication.
I always get the 401 error and I am sure that username and password are correct. Here is the code I used (I saw this code here: [How can I pass credentials while using NSURLSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784837/how-can-i-pass-credentials-while-using-nsurlsession)). Suggestions? Thank you!

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl...."];

NSString *user = @"userna,e";
NSString *password = @"password";
NSURLCredential *defaultCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:user password:password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent];

NSString *host = [url host];
NSInteger port = [[url port] integerValue];
NSString *protocol = [url scheme];

NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc] initWithHost:host port:port protocol:protocol realm:nil authenticationMethod:NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic];

NSURLCredentialStorage *credentials = [NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage];
[credentials setDefaultCredential:defaultCredential forProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
[config setURLCredentialStorage:credentials];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
        NSLog(@"%d", httpResp.statusCode);
    }

}] resume];

...

// ONLY FOR SELF-SIGNED CERTIFICATE!!! DANGEROUS!!
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler
{
    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential,credential);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For basic auth I didn't manage to getting working with the way the docs described but I could just do exactly what the docs say not to do and set the header directly on the session.

This is the Swift version.

```
   let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
   sessionConfig.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization":"Basic fjdslkfsdfk="]
```

I think you can also set them directly on the request. Obj-C equivalent is left as an exercise for the reader.

There is a [good blog post here](https://medium.com/swift-programming/learn-nsurlsession-using-swift-ebd80205f87c) that explains how the credential delegate should be used.

Comment: of course, it is the simplest solution, but it works :)
my request was to better understand NSURLSession and its delegates.
anyway, +1

Comment: @FabioMignogna Fair enough. I may try again to get the proper way working and update but saw it unanswered having had problems recently. I'm not sure if those issues were due to a bad server (sending 400 not 401) or because there isn't really a challenge in basic authorization or something else. I've added a link to a good recent post by someone else.

Comment: How is the "fjdslkfsdfk=" part calculated?

Comment: I'd forgotten but it seems it is "username:password" base64 encoded. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication